# What's the difference between the open source licences

Tags: language-agnostic

I read all the licenses, and frankly I am kindda baffled by the many choices available. I know some relax the limitation of the license so that open source stuff can be used in commercial applications.
But other than that, why are there so many licenses out there? Is there any **major** difference between them. How do I go about choosing the right one for me?

To not make this too general and complicated I'll just throw in some licenses here and you guys can tell me what's the main point of each

1. gpl (v2/v3)
2. Apache license
3. BSD license
4. The MIT license
5. The mozilla license

Edit: 
(Pointed out to me, by 3 people, no less) whether or not a license allows a user to use the software in a commercial software is covered [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137048/how-do-i-tell-if-i-can-re-use-a-free-software-library-in-a-commercial-app). But, as stated, I'm also looking if someone can shed light on the difference other than that. In context of choosing one for my own project rather than in the context of whether or not I can use the software within my own commercial software ( like I believe the other thread is about )

Comment: this is NOT an exact duplicate, question is about ALL diffs, not just library-reuse diffs.

Comment: yes, why was this closed?  argh, stupid feature

Comment: I reopen my question because some agree that this is not an exact duplicate.

Comment: I think this site will help you:

http://choosealicense.com/

Comment: A better stackexchange to ask this is http://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are important differences among the different licenses available. To explain them here, as you asked, would be like reinventing the wheel.

I suggest looking at the site @raphael75 suggested: [Choose an open source license](http://choosealicense.com/)